# How does this scam involving buying a used car cash-only work?

Tags: canada, car, scams, used-goods

I'm in pursuit of a used car. I came across this 2010 Camry for 4200 CAD. The car is good, I test drove it in the city and on the highway and there are no problems with it as far as I can tell. However, the seller is selling cash only. He doesn't accept e-transfer. The following are a couple text messages between me and him:

[image: Text conversation]

Other info: The seller has met with me in his workplace. So that's good. I told him that I want to get a CARFAX report, hence I need the VIN (Vehicle Identification Number) of the car. He gave the VIN. I didn't get a CARFAX but I'm assuming that if it had a lien on the car, he wouldn't have given it.

So what is it? It feels sketchy to me but I can't pinpoint if it's a scam or not.

Comment: You should summarize those text messages.  Why are you referring to not-cash as cash?  You're trying to pay with not-cash.  Why don't you want to pay in cash in person?

Comment: @quid I'm trying to pay with non-cash. The seller wants cash. I want bank transfer because if anything goes south, I would have evidence.

Comment: What part of this do you think is a scam?  In reading those messages the suspicious one is you, because you are complicating what should be a simple cash transaction.

Comment: @quid If there is a fraud with the title or something, there is no way that I can go after the guy if I paid cash.

Comment: yes there is.  You both sign a bill of sale and receipt that acknowledges the cash payment.

Comment: @quid I'm not sure about that. This is Canada.

Comment: Did Canada make cash transactions illegal?  Canadian courts don't acknowledge cash transactions?  https://www.carfax.ca/resource-centre/articles/how-to-finalize-a-private-used-car-sale

Comment: Most suggestions for dealing online with cars is cash only, in person, no exceptions. Never heard of getting a car with keys and a fake title, weird and risky way to try to get rid of a stolen car (or equivalently weird situation). Not something I've ever heard of or been warned of by a credible source. If there was a lien that's a super obvious and traceable crime on their part, fraud, having an electronic transfer would not be particularly helpful.

Comment: @BrianH That makes sense. I guess the car is legit in that case.

Comment: You are right to be skeptical of transactions with unknown parties, so many scams. But thus the in- person cash for goods in hand rule. For added security, complete the exchange in a public place with security cams around, like a bank, police station, etc, and bring a second person as witness if you are extra concerned. But the cash part is normal.

Comment: @Utku "_there is no way that I can go after the guy if I paid cash_" Can't see it makes a difference. If, as you say about the E-Transfer "_once it's in your account, it cannot get out._", it doesn't sound like there's a way of stopping the payment, so if something went wrong, in both cases you would have to sue the original owner, AFAICT.

Comment: Congratulations!  We *regularly* get "is this a scam" questions here.  Yours is one of the very select few to which the answer is "no".

Comment: For what it means, this partially feels like a generational thing. Ive noticed in several countries ive been to younger folks (myself included) are generally very squeamish about using physical cash for much anything. While people who have been around longer seem to think it completely normal. I think there are dramatically varying norms on who feels using cash for transactions is normal and ok or not...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is almost certainly not a scam.  This is the seller trying to avoid any chance of you scamming him, with for instance a fake transfer.  While I don't know details of Canadian motor vehicle laws, in the US such a cash transaction would be the normal way to handle a sale between private parties where there's no outstanding vehicle loan.

FWIW, the only private party sale I've ever done that wasn't cash was a cashier's check for the price I hoped to bargain the seller down to, and cash for the difference between that and the price we eventually agreed on.